# Angular, ng-href causing page to refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty simple ng-href feeding off of an object in a repeat that is causing a little issue. Everywhere else on my app, if I use ng-href it keeps the single page feel and does not refresh the app, however in this instance it seems to be refreshing the page and I can't figure out why.

```
 <md-button ng-if="category.link" ng-href="/{{category.link}}">
```

I just have this inside of a repeat, feeding off a repeated object, which just says show this button if it has a link and attaches the ng-href to it (using angular-material buttons).

The link works fine, it's just refreshing the page. Any insight would be very helpful, I can't seem to figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref . At the example with slash in front it says: `(link, reload!)`

Comment: have you enabled $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);?

Comment: can you add the routing configuration code?

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem but it turned out to be a javascript library added a click handler which called `e.stopPropagation()`. Once we took that out angular started handling the links so there was no page reload. We use ui-router so we suspected it was the culprit but it wasn't.

We discovered the click handler was the problem because the page reload only happened for links inside a particular menu. Anywhere else the links with ng-href worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Put a hash (#) infront of slash(/) to make angular router work instead of reloading the page.

```
<md-button ng-if="category.link" ng-href="#/{{category.link}}">
```

Comment: what happen if $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); ?

Comment: @pankajparkar Pls read the question carefully, OP mentioned that Everywhere else on my app, if I use ng-href it keeps the single page feel and does not refresh the app... Without enabling html5mode, is that possible?

Comment: yes, if you enable html5Mode then hash prefix will went away,,